# algorithm of chat application in java using sockets

Tags: java, sockets, jsp, jakarta-ee

I have to make a web application for chat which will work as skype, like 1 to 1 chat as well as group chat.

Last some days i am researching on google and i come to know following things.

For making speed better, i must use sockets. Database must in involved for storing the history of chat.

Last 1 year, i am working on java but unfortunately never worked on socket connection.

There are some online code available, even i tried to understand it as well but its all gone above my head.

But couple of things i come to know as follows

1. Server class need to configure the sockets.
2. client class need to send the message through the sockets.

My question is how i will come to know that a specific message is send to specific group or person...??

As only 1 socket is connecting to all group, a particular message will go to all.

I do not need a example, i just need to make a algorithm right so that i can start work on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your server and client will have group property

So client will send a message lets call it as Message object

```
class MessageObject {

 String message;

 String group;
}
```

Your server will have keep a note of all client and depending upon group it will store them say in a map.

Whenever a new message comes to the server, it will check the group of the message and depending upon it, from the map it will get a list of clients and will write the message on to there stream.

Answer (score 1):

The [chat sample](https://github.com/mmcbride/atmosphere/tree/master/samples) of atmosphere should give you enough to get you started.

Answer (score 1):

[This ppt](https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http://www.cs.uah.edu/~weisskop/Notes690/A13_Elections.ppt) could help you to start

I recommend you check a book about distributed systems or network communication